# Poor image quality using the batik SVGConverter from svg to png

Tags: svg, png, batik

I'm using batik to convert an existing svg file to a png. Unfortunately, the png output is low quality. The text and images are both fuzzy. I haven't been able to find anywhere that can show me how to maximize the quality in this process. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
        SVGConverter svgConverter = new SVGConverter();
        svgConverter.setMaxWidth(580);
        svgConverter.setDestinationType(DestinationType.PNG);
        svgConverter.setSources(new String[]{ svgSource.toURI().toURL().toString() });


        svgConverter.setDst(outputPng);
        svgConverter.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I found that it made a difference which JVM I was running (try `java -version`)

Sun's Java SE (build 1.6.0_24-b07) gave me decent results.  The 'standard' JVM installed on my Linux version (CentOS): OpenJDK IcedTea6 1.9.8 gave disappointing results.

I actually doubt that it's the JVM, it's more likely to be some library provided with the different installations, but I haven't the time or enthusiasm to dig any deeper. I'm just happy that I finally have some credible PNGs!

I hope this is of some use to you.

James

Comment: We ended up scrapping the use of svg files altogether but I'll look into that if I'm ever forced to deal with this issue again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the attribute.indexed

indexed: relevant only for PNG, controls the number of bits used in writting of a palletized files.

I imagine it would look like
svgConverter.setindexed(10);

Comment: I tried that but didn't see a difference. I tried two other methods that might be useful but they don't seem to help either. Probably because I don't know what values would help. I've tried really big numbers and really small numbers with no noticeable difference: setPixelUnitToMillimeter(float pixelUnitToMillimeter) and setQuality(float quality). setQuality is for JPEG files but I'd be willing to switch to JPEG if I could actually get the quality to improve. I figure there's got to be a way to do this or no one would use batik.